# How mush clients SSE supports?

Tags: sockets, http2, server-sent-events

Let's assume there are a several clients that must receive updated data from server. They connect to server and communicate using Server Sent Event push.

How SSE knows that concrete message should be addressed to concrete client like it works in sockets?

Does it support broadcast or private messages?

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How SSE knows that concrete message should be addressed to concrete client like it works in sockets?

The client connects to an URL on the server. You can optionally add *query parameters* to the URL that can be used for logic.

Since the client have initiated the connection, the server must all the time hold a "handle" to this connection, so it can use it to send data. In this way, it is similar to sockets.

> Does it support broadcast or private messages?

The server must iterate over all *connection handles* to send data to all clients. It can send data to only some clients, similar to private messages. How the connections is handled is up to the server.

Comment: Hi,could you share an sample how to send message only for specific clients? Also can one client open some sse connections? For example bybone sent private messages, by another notifications and so on

Comment: Is it correct that sse craetes private connection one to one? Can it be one to many?

Comment: It is one connection from the client to the server. But many clients can use Server Sent Events to connect to the same server.